# clear:left too greedy in 2 column layout

Tags: html, css

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/YUhgb/

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
            <p>
                After Container
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.left{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color:red;
}
.right{
    margin-left: 160px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.container:after{
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.item{
    float:left;
    width: 21%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

The problem is, if the left column is too long, the content below the floated content drops down below the left side. In my example, I want the text `After Container` to be displayed directly below the green boxes.

How can I apply the clear:left so that it only affects the right column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by adding `display: table` and `width: 100%;` to your block with a class of `container`. See the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/YUhgb/15/

Comment: The first time I tried it, I got a horizontal scrollbar. Looking at it again, it appears to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this whole CSS block:

```
.container:after{
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

...and add:

```
.container { overflow:auto; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YUhgb/12/

Cheers

Comment: This is a good answer, but in my real code I have some `.container` blocks that also have a background color. Not having the clear after the floating elements is causing the background color not to clear the entire container. Otherwise, the content is laid out correctly.

Comment: Well, you need to included that in your question then.

Answer (score 0):

You could float your right column as well?

Modified Example : http://jsfiddle.net/YUhgb/9/

Comment: Yes, but this only works if you are able to set the width of the right column.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `float:left;` on `.left` to `position: absolute;` and it is displaying how I want it.

Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/YUhgb/17/

Comment: Forgive me, but it's not a good solution. Watch what happens if you add a footer to that page: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/YUhgb/18/ Absolute positioning should be treated carefully :)

Comment: You're correct. I actually do have a footer, but for now it's working for me because my `After container` is pretty tall and the right side is always longer than the left. However, I should still seek a better solution.

Comment: Actually I proposed a better solution 53 minutes ago))) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10305534/1144057